# AuthenticationService accessing from code behind

Tags: .net, forms-authentication

I want to call my AuthenticationService from the code behind of my .net application.  This is the build in wcf forms authentication service.

How can I do this?

I can't seem to figure out how to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot instantiate AuthenticationService Class.

You can initialize it like this:
private readonly AuthenticationService authService = WebContext.Current.Authentication;